# Rails: Google or other Social Network sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

How can I make people comment my blog made using Ruby on Rails using google/facebook sign in?

Does anybody have any simple working examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing it (on example of facebook).
First way is just to use FB social plugins, no custom code at all, just inserting in your HTML files default code of FB API.
Here you can add FB authentications, like button, comment board. Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Another way is custom option, based on FB API.
Omniauth gems provide all needed to authentication, and you can find a lot of tutorials.
This way you can add more social interactions, add custom activities, which will be displayed in user timeline, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I'm actually not that interested in Facebook signin/comments. Is there an equivalent for Google+?

Comment: I don't know about social plugins, but omniauth is provided for every network I know, including google+